# soft constraint on list size is ignored. why?

Tags: specman, e

It seems that Specman is ignoring a constraint on list size. Is there an explanation to this behavior?

I have this code:

```
m:list of uint;
keep soft m == {};
```

In my test I have this constraint:

```
keep soft m.size() == 3;
```

But I still get empty list. Why is that? I expected the later soft constraint to hold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the *Inteligen User Guide* there is a section on *List Assignment*. It mentions that when you have a constraint of type `list1 == read_only(list2)` the size and the elements of `list1` don't get generated. This is means that any constraints on `list1.size()` are not enforced.

In your case you're doing kind of the same thing. Even though you don't have `read_only(...)` explicitly written, `{}` is a constant, so you're basically assigning the empty list to `m`. The generator doesn't enforce the last constraint, as the user guide says. To see that this is the case, you can remove the `soft` modifier from both constraints and you'll see that you don't get any contradiction error.

If you change the initial constraint (`soft m == {}`) to `soft m.size() == 0` you get the expected behavior, i.e. the list has 3 elements. This is because you don't do list assignment anymore, so constraints on `m.size()` will get enforced.